# Trouble with defining variable in classes (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Update

```
data[j][i]
```

j = the rows in the file and i = columns. 
What I am trying to do is somehow linking my attributes to each representing a value of i.

```
Name Match Won Loss Tie goal_done goal_letin points
bla   0    0    0    0     0         0        0
```

So I am basically trying to somehow changing linking or changing this  `data[h-1][i] += 1` into an attribute or as I wanted to before, having "i" somehow like an attribute

```
def hemmalag_bortalag(data):
print("Numererad Laglista: \n 1. Arsenal \n 2. Man Utd \n 3. Liverpool \n 4. Newcastle")
ange_lag(data)


    hx = int(input("Hur många mål gjorde hemmalaget?\n"))
    bx = int(input("Hur många mål gjorde bortalaget?\n"))

    if hx > bx:
        print("Hemmalaget vann!")
        hemmalag.match(data)  #<-------        data[i-1][j] += 1 # Assign to the index of the column and row
         data[h-1][2] +=1
         data[h-1][5] +=hx
         data[h-1][6] +=bx
         data[h-1][7] +=3

         data[b-1][1] +=1
         data[b-1][4] +=1
         data[b-1][5] +=bx
         data[b-1][6] +=hx  


    print("Listan är nu uppdaterad!")
    b=h

def ange_lag(data):
h = int(input("Var god skriv hemmalag\n"))
b = int(input("Var god skriv bortalag\n"))
hemmalag = data[h][i]
bortalag = data[b][antal]        


def lagplacering
namn = data[h-1][0]
match = data[h-1][1]
match_vunnen = data[h-1][2]
match_förlorad = data[h-1][3]
match_oavgjord = data[h-1][4]
mål_insläppta = data[h-1][5]
mål_gjorda = data[h-1][6]
poäng = data[h-1][7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `i` in the default constructor:

```
class Lag:

   def __init__(self,namn,match,match_vunnen,match_förlorad, match_oavgjord,insläppta_mål,gjorda_mål,poäng)
       self.i = 1
       self.namn = namn
       self.match = int(match)
       self.match_vunnen = int(match_vunnen)
       self.match_förlorad = int(match_förlorad)
       self.match_oavgjord = int(match_oavgjord)
       self.mål_insläppta = int(mål_insläppta)
       self.mål_gjorda = int(mål_gjorda)
       self.poäng = int(poäng)
```

Now, every method in the class `Lag` will be able to access and mutate `i`

Comment: and why `self.i=1`considering I want i to be different variables amongs the classes

Comment: If you want it to be different you can add it to the list of `__init__` args. Or, if it's supposed to be the id of the object, you could make it say `self.i = id(self)`

Comment: @PythonGirl regarding your first question, in ordered to use `i` in the class methods, you now have to call them by `self.i`. For your second question, if you want a separate variable `i`, then the code you are using now should work. However, if you need `i` in a global sense, you can copy the value stored in `self.i` to another variable such as `new_variable = self.i`.

Comment: BTW, all the time you're talking about "classes" (plural), but as far as I can see you defined just one class named `Lag`. I sense some basic misunderstanding of the concept of class here.

Comment: Yes its just the language barrier

Comment: I only need to define i as far as i can change the data[y][i] as I would like to

Comment: I am not sure if that needs to implement another self.i for

Comment: @PythonGirl could you post a smaller sample of your code, sample input, and your desired output from that input?